# How to deserialize a XMLSerializer object with ByteArrayOutputStream as Output

Tags: android, xml

I have a code like this to make a serialize xml file:

```
private byte[] bytes;
...
OutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
XmlSerializer newSerializer = Xml.newSerializer();
newSerializer.setOutput(byteArrayOutputStream, "utf-8");
newSerializer.startDocument("utf-8", null);
newSerializer.startTag(null, "playlist");
newSerializer.attribute(null, "version", "1.0");
...
put all my XML tags
...

newSerializer.endTag(null, "playlist");
newSerializer.endDocument();
this.bytes= byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
```

What i need to do: convert this byte Array into a XML file again and i don´t know how to do it!

Comment: Do you need to just save it into a file or something more?

Comment: I send this ByteArray to a socket.
But i dont know how to deserialize it.

Comment: How exactly do you want to deserialize it? From the socket side, do you want to do something like `file.getTag(...)` or you just want to save it as a file?

Comment: I just need to get the XML file exactly as I've formatted it.

Comment: You already pass the bytes that contain exactly the XML as you formatted.

Comment: But how , in the code, i can deserialize the bytes to XML?

Comment: And here we return to my original question. What exactly do you want? You can save these bytes to a file and it will be your xml.

Comment: I need to see the XML tags and your values, i just need it

Comment: Do you need just a string? Or something more?

Comment: The Key - Value of the tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can change your existing serialisation and deserialisation as follows:

```
try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
        os.writeObject(newSerializer);
        ObjectInputStream oin = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray()));
        return (XmlSerializer) oin.readObject();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Exception("Exception occurred:" + e.getMessage(), e);
    }
```